# Manually validating a token from an OIDC provider without `well-known` metadata in Asp Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openid

I'm using a flow with Openid, where I redirect my user to another provider, to take care about login, and after this login I receive the `code` in my /login/callback?code=xxxx URL.

So, the JWT is generated using the `code` but I can't validate it. I don't have `well-known` endpoint in my STS, I need to configure manually in this way:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", cfgPolicy =>
            {
                cfgPolicy.AddRequirements().RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                cfgPolicy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            });
        }).AddAuthentication(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ClientId = authenticationConfig.ClientId;
            cfg.ClientSecret = authenticationConfig.ClientSecret;
            cfg.ResponseType = "code";
            cfg.CallbackPath = "/login/callback";
            cfg.Scope.Clear();
            cfg.Scope.Add("openid");
            
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = "https://myissuer"
            };

            cfg.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
            {
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://mysts/api/oauth/authorize",
                TokenEndpoint = "https://mysts/api/oauth/token",
                UserInfoEndpoint = "https://mysts/api/oauth/token_info"
            };
        });
```

Some important points:

1. I have a token instrospection endpoint, to validate my token (token_info endpoint).
2. I don't have an default endpoint to return public keys (jwks). My endpoint is always a concat from some values, something like that --> https://mysts/offline/jwks/{kid}/{clientid}, so this is dynamic and depends of the token.
3. I don't have a well-known endpoint.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's your question? You want us to help you what ?

Comment: _"i have a token instrospection endpoint"_, you can also submit each token to introspection endpoint for validation, and that would probably be easier to implement, but end up slower in terms of execution (given it's sync-over-async and all that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validate it because, ASP.NET Core tries to validate the JWT signature by default. However, since you've set up the metadata yourself, and not given a `JwksUri`, it has no way of getting the public key of the OIDC provider to validate the signature against.

You can specify the `JwksUri`, or turn off signature validation (**NOT SECURE**), or validate it yourself. If you have access to the public key, somehow, use `options.SecurityTokenValidator` and implement a `ISecurityTokenValidator` for custom validation.

Here's a (non-tested) implementation that fetches the JWKS dynamically and validates a token:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
            options.SecurityTokenValidator = new MyJwtValidator(Configuration);
        });
}

class MyJwtValidator: ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler;

    public MyJwtValidator(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        _httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("OidcProvider").Get<string>())
        };
    }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken) => true;

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(
        string securityToken,
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
        out SecurityToken validatedToken
    )
    {
        // parse the token (without validating) to extract a value
        var parsedToken = new JwtSecurityToken(securityToken);
        var keyId = parsedToken.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "kid").Value;
        
        // fetch JWKS and validate the token
        var clientId = _configuration.GetSection("OidcProvider:ClientId").Get<string>();
        var jwks = _httpClient.GetStringAsync($"url/to/jwks/{keyId}/{clientId}").Result;
        // jwks == "{ keys: [..."
        var signingKeys = new JsonWebKeySet(jwks).GetSigningKeys();

        return _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(securityToken, new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys
        }, out validatedToken);
    }

    public bool CanValidateToken { get; } = true;
    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;
}
```

It's doing sync-over-async, which is frowned upon, but you might wanna cache the keys to avoid paying the penalty.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this solution, to make my own validation token.